# composite Image using Imagick php function with transperent

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

i create image using Imagick function . i use **wood.png** as row image , **1.jpg** is over right on **wood.png** . problem is i need to see wood image as transparent of **1.jpg**.
i also upload **result.png** but we need same as **need.png**.

```
$width =  300;
$height = 400;
$image = new Imagick("wood.png");
$image->cropImage($width,$height, 0,0);
$current_image = new Imagick();
$current_image->readImage('1.jpg');
$current_image->cropImage($current_image->getImageWidth(),$current_image->getImageHeight(), 0, 0);
$current_image->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
$image->compositeImage($current_image, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

[image: result.png]
[image: need.png][image][image]

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. I think you want to overlay something onto something else maybe with some transparency. Can you supply two very simple starting images and a result image that shows what you want rather than two images of different sizes please? You do realise you cannot have transparency in a JPEG, don't you?

Comment: I added 2 images more . round image will be place on wood image . also first image is my result . and second image is my wishes .

Comment: Does this command in the shell in Terminal give you the correct result? `convert swirl.jpg -resize 343x513! wood.png -compose overlay -composite result.png`

Comment: i test this code in php .

Comment: Try using `imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY` in place of `imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER`.

Comment: http://madi.metizcloud.com/demo/Createimage.png
i already do this . but image will be disturb. see above url .

If you need to code then tell me I give you FTP . All is ready here.